# Does the Box read Subconscious Mind?

Tags: experimental-physics, experimental-technology

I was watching [this](https://vimeo.com/203242252) video from MindField channel on YouTube red, earlier also known as Vsauce on YouTube, which freaks me out when the Box tells you what button you are going to press, what was going on there, can any one please explain, for first 15 minutes the box collects data from brain and then the fun begins.

Comment: This has nothing to do with physics.

Comment: Please do not rely on external links for your question, since those can rot away. Currently, without watching the video, it is unclear what "box" you are talking about or what this has to do with physics.

Answer (score 3):

I enjoyed the demonstration of how "visualizations" precede actions. I have reached the age, 77 in two months, where I have discovered this by the way I think I have done something , but in reality was satisfied with the "visualization" (at the time the intent was taken) and did not act it up.

A good example is the water heater, which for economic reasons we turn on and off for a limited time ( I live in Greece and my pension has been cut by 60% and the process is downhill). If I do not put on the clock at alarm for the time I want , often, when the time comes I have the impression I turned it off just by having visualized it (must turn off, at the time of putting it on, by a full "visualization").

This is very annoying for things like taking something with you on a trip, and finding that you were satisfied with the "visualization" of doing it.

They are just exploring the mechanisms between muscle action and "visualization".  The subconscious and whether there is free choice comes before that.

I put "visualization" in quotes because it is really a whole five senses feeling, in the case of the water heater "lifting up the hand, turning down the switch and expecting the click".

Making check lists helps.